# Is it possible to adjust Interface based on xml in IOS

Tags: ios, xml, user-interface

I am having an idea to adjust the positions of objects/elements used in interface based on xml file which is having the positions of that objects/elements.

for eg:

[image]

Based on this tags button has to adjust the positions.

I need to know is this possible in IOS. If YES, How is it possible?
If NO, Why it is not possible?

Edit: I am adding xml file to my project.

Answer (score 0):

Your options are limited, the only one I've seen before is [Workflow Schema](https://github.com/CRedit360/WorkflowSchema) which does do pretty much what you are saying.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible, Parse the xml file and get the values of height and width then u can adjust the position of button using [button setFrame:CGRectMake(x,y,width,height).

Comment: yes amith, what you said is correct. but I am going to add xml file to project. and whenever i am going to change that xml file in project, elements has to change according to that xml file. is it possible?